# c++ static const variables and ROMable

Tags: c++, generics, template-meta-programming, sections, rom

I have been reading up on that const variables declared in the global scope are stored in .rodata. which I now understand is read-only data. Often apparently that is stored in ROM.

I have started reading up on Template Meta Programming in C++. so I am firstly wondering why it needs to be in .rodata or static const such as

```
template<int N>
struct is_even<N>{
      static const bool value = N % 2 == 0;
}
```

why does it have to be static const?
also what does this buy me?
Whats the significance of being in .rodata?
whats the significance of being so called ROMable?

I understand templates as it is similar to generics in C# I use. But just much more powerfull.

What I am trying to understand is why are these constraints necessary and what does the compiler do with them whilst evaluating my program.

Any links and references welcome.

Blair

Comment: An application's read-only data is stored in RAM. ROM – Read-Only Memory – can only ever be read from. A read-only section of RAM is a completely different thing; its read-only status can be changed at runtime.

Comment: @molbdnilo  "An application's read-only data is stored in RAM."  Hogwash.   It's implementation-dependent. In desktop/server environments, none of your program or data will be in ROM anyway, unless you're writing BIOS code. On embedded systems, it's common for statically-allocated 'const' data to be linked in ROM (e.g. the .rodata section), if you have your project (BSP) and initialization code set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to have const variables in ROM or in any other place. That is an implementation detail. Some compilers may place them in ROM and others not.

The compiler only has to guarantee that well formed C++ programs always get the declared value when such variable is accessed.

In some systems there is a large ammount of available ROM and little RAM. An example of such system is the Nintendo DS wich has 4Mb of RAM but the rom is in the cartridge, which can be in the hundreds of Mb. In such systems you should put everything in ROM if possible and reserve RAM only for variables which truly change in time; because RAM is scarce and ROM not. So the gain here is that the program fits but if you put const variables in RAM it might not fit.

Comment: To be completely correct, it's not the compiler that places data or code into ROM, it's the linker. But even then, that's not totally true: The linker places data/code into whatever address ranges are specified for various code/data sections in a linker command file, or linker configuration file, which you can modify if you want. Of course that's not necessary for desktop/server environments, the system-provided linker command file should suffice. But in embedded systems, the linker will put the content at whatever address range you specify for each section. If that range is in ROM, so be it.

Comment: @phonetagger If you wish to engage into complete correctness... the one which places data or code into the ROM is the manufacturing plant, the EPROM writter or similar devices.

Comment: OK, sure, if you want to be completely correct. But since most end-user target devices can reprogram their own flash ROM nowadays, you don't necessarily need a separate device to write to ROM. Which means if you want to split hairs, it's technically not "Read Only Memory" per the strictest meaning of the term. ***If*** you want to be ***completely*** correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

c++ has no standard facilities to place any data in ROM, since there is no concept of RAM/ROM in the language.

Some compilers will do it in some instances as a side effect, but there is no standard for doing it.

Another reason why C and C++ are the worst languages ever created.